# SignIn Authentication

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-signin

I need a user to SignIn with his email id in my application. The email is a domain of google for example) xyz@abc.ac.in

Now, I want the application to authenticate the signin and accept only this domain. If the user selects any other account configured on the device then it should say Invalid user and must not let him sign in. This is my code

```
if(currentAccount.endsWith("abc.ac.in"))
{
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.email)).setText(currentAccount);
}
else
{
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
}
```

Now what's happening here is that when the user enters some other email, the application says Invalid User but lets him sign in. What should be done in order to make revoke the signin permission of the user when an invalid email is entered?

Comment: If your condition is true then only let the user do other task else just show the user a message and stop there. You must have added sign in code after if else block. you should put that in you condition.

Comment: @Kunu Yes, I have added that but I forgot to mention that if the email entered is invalid then I don't have to show a message but I need to repeat the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

When you are able to retrieve the email and check whether it satisfies your condition or not, don't go ahead with the other processes(like sending details to the server or going to the next screen) and do them when your condition is satisfied.